# Read more module / script magento

Tags: jquery, css, magento

I have installed a module in magento to handel the read more or less function like they talk about here:

[How to add jquery readmore function (expand/collapse) to magento CMS pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876420/how-to-add-jquery-readmore-function-expand-collapse-to-magento-cms-pages)

But there are two things im currently having trubels with.

1. The text is beeign [cut off by the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtO1P.jpg) ( im looking for a solution that will work on all resolutions )
2. i want to control the styling of the links ( smaller, position, color ) but working with css looks impossible

[This is my magento store](http://goo.gl/zlltLt)

Can anybody help me with this ?

Comment: Can you post code examples? Descriptions of problems and links to websites are not the best way to get help on stackoverflow. Better to show what you've done, how you've tried to debug and address the problem, and to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to adjust the height of the collapsed window to the same as for example the first paragraph if you want this to work across all viewport sizes.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var h = $('#readomore-demo').find("p:first").height();
     $('.readmore-js-collapsed').css("height", h);
 });
```

Styling the links should be simple enough, they have a ready made class.